# How do I get C# Dotnet Intellisense to work on Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, omnisharp

I'm learning to use Unity under Ubuntu 20.04

Following the coding tutorials, I have downloaded Visual Studio Code and Dotnet for Ubuntu (version 6.0.300)

The code I write works (if I get it correct) but despite installing and enabling the Extension for C# and Ominsharp displaying no errors, I get no Intellisense, no error checking and no code hints at all when developing - so Visual Studio Code is currently nothing but a glorified Notepad app.

I read that Omnisharp would only work up to Dotnet 6.0.100 but I have found no path to downgrade from 6.0.300 to 6.0.100 - in fact, I found no download for 6.0.100 at all

How do I get things working correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was to enable the Roslyn analyzers in VS Code and set "Use Global Mono" to always.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to have helped. Maybe I messed up something more basic- what instructions did you use to get set up?